# normal map problem for mirrored dupli groups in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, normals

A building front is created by placing group instances as *dupli groups*.

The group is a wall element with an asymmetric window which is placed in the scene 
alternately mirrored and not mirrored.

When texturing the elements with a normal map texture
I noticed a different result for the mirrored group instances.

[image]

I guess the problem is caused by the mirrored mesh normals of the mirrored group instances
because without normal maps the result is the same for both orientations.

Is there a solution to solve this texture problem without dropping the dupli groups?
I use the dupli groups as a fast way to generate design alternatives.